# how to work with ros time

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have saved some gps data using the gps fix message type. In this message, the gps data has a field called %time.

Except, this %time data is kind of weird. The format the %time values are in is of the following:

1355859745049430000

1355859746522960000

1355859747052170000

...

How do I convert this time data to something that I can work with, for example, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 seconds, etc.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54704/how-to-work-with-ros-time/) by [mte2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/2294/mte2010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see any ROS functions for doing this, but here's an algorithm in PHP that you could use: [http://www.andrews.edu/~tzs/timeconv/timealgorithm.html](http://www.andrews.edu/%7Etzs/timeconv/timealgorithm.html)

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mte2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/2294/mte2010/) on 2013-02-10**:
Hmm, this is talking about gps time. I looked into my data a bit more, and I found that: -this time data is actually rostime and not gps time, so basically I capture this gps data using play [rosbag_file_name] and then I just listen to my gps topic. So this time data is the same time data as rosbag

**Comment by [mte2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/2294/mte2010/) on 2013-02-10**:
So, how would I convert this rosbag time to something in seconds that makes sense? Once again, this rosbag time looks like this: 1355885782739630000, 1355885782763280000, and my loop rate is at 50 hz or 0.02 seconds

**Comment by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on 2013-02-10**:
The time field of the GPSFix message is supposed to be GPS time... how is that field getting filled? The ROS time should be in GPSFix.header.stamp